# Will changing an object from a hashmap affect the wait() method in multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking

I have a hashmap of objects. Access to the hashmap is synchronized. Each object has a condition on whether or not it can be altered. If the object is not available via condition, object.wait(); is called and the current thread waits. If it is available, the object is altered and then put back into the hashmap:

```
HashMap<String, Boolean> availabilityMap = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
HashMap<String, Object> objectMap = new  HashMap<String, Object>();
...
...

lock() {
     while (!availabilityMap.get(objectName)) {
          object = objectMap.get(objectName);
          object.wait();
     } 
     availabilityMap.put(objectName, false);
     object = objectMap.get(objectName);
}

object.attribute = newValue;

lock() {
     objectMap.put(objectName, object);
     availabilityMap.put(objectName, true);
     object = objectMap.get(objectName);
     object.notify();
}
```

Say thread1 is changing the attribute of this object, and thread2 is waiting to access the object. Thread1 finishes altering it, puts it back into the hashmap, and calls object.notify(). *Will that object in thread2 still get the notification?*

Comment: Your code won't work as written, because you can only call `wait` on `notify` if you are currently `synchronized` on that object. If you're not, you'll get an `IllegalMonitorStateException`

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather obscure. The only things that will affect a `wait()` method are:

1. `notify()` or `notifyAll()` called on the same object.
2. `Thread.interrupt()`.

If you `notify()` and only one thread is in `wait()`, that thread will get the notification. If multiple threads are in `wait()`, only one of them will get it. That's what `notifyAll()` is for.

> Say thread1 is changing the attribute of this object, and thread2 is waiting to access the object. Thread1 finishes altering it, puts it back into the hashmap, and calls `object.notify()`. Will that object in thread2 still get the notification?

Of course. Why not? Getting it out of the hashmap and putting it back has nothing to do with it.